# TouchableOpacity do not working when a lottie file is on the screen

Tags: react-native, android-animation, lottie

I have a lottie file and a child component in the same screen. The child component contain a `TouchableOpacity`. But it did not working because of the lottie file. When I remove Lottie file from the screen the `TouchableOpacity` works properly.

Here is my code.

```
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>

   <Child userName={userName} />

  <LottieView
    style={styles.anime}
    source={require('../../assets/40375-health-loader-radar.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
  />

</View>
);
```

How can I make that TouchableOpacity work?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. All I needed to do is add a `zIndex=1` to the child component.